# Is there a known formula of the speed distribution of distinct layers in the frame-dragging region of a BH?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, rotation, frame-dragging

I am asking this question only because I want to figure out does space move in this case similarly to a fluid like water or oil are or even more better as speeds o planets around a star.. or this phenomena has a different formula describing a complex effect caused by the gravity as a force deriving from S-T curvature? Thanks in advance for an 'easy to understand' answer....

Comment: The equations for the frame dragging angular and local velocity can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman%E2%80%93de%E2%80%93Sitter_metric) where you can also find an [animation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Frame_dragging_of_locally_stationary_ZAMOs.gif) of frame dragged ZAMOs. If you had a fluid it would depend on it's viscocity, so maybe you are asking about the viscocity of spacetime, but we do already have some postings on that.

Comment: @Yukterez So if a body approaching a RBH in direction of frame rotation enters in the fast,  inner parts of the FD region and then manages to leave that region it would not gain any extra velocity deriving from the Rot.BH energy? In Simpler words there is no way to extract the RBH energy?

Comment: You can extract with the Penrose Process, see [MTW, Fig. 33.2](https://i.imgur.com/m24xB5q.png)